# google app engine first query slowly after instance created

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I develop application in google app engine with jpa eclipselink.
I have instance in google app engine.

I have problem with the first query after the instance of server created. the first time the query is called takes a lot of time 30 sec but in second time the same query take 700 milisec
why is happen and who i can fix it
I added pictures form logs of server with problem
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Post text in the question, not images (that are unreadable). If something takes a long time then the SQL that is executed is where to look, compared to the JPQL that was invoked

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible Environment?

Comment: Hi LundinCast
I use App Engine Standard

Comment: HI  Billy Frost you can open the image in new tab and then you can read the text in image I put the text in image because I think is help you to understand the problem and you can see the log of server thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is perfect normal in a Cloud environment. The first request generally takes longer for exactly the reason you see in the logs (it's causing a new instance to spin up).

You can read about how instances scaling works [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed). There are many ways to lessen the instances load time, one of which is [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/warmup-requests/), you also simply use manual scaling and always have an instance ready to service if you like.

Ultimately, please go through the documentation and choose what suits your need the best.

Comment: HI thank you for replay I read the documentation and change from scaling instance to manual and is work good Thank you a lot